# Javafx scale a control according to it's parent

Tags: javafx-8

I am writing a new Imageview with mask in Javafx.
The mask can show according to the direction of mouse.
Using Timeline makes it work well. But when the mask leaves, the mask is still visible.
I want to hide the part of mask, which is out of the Image. How can I scale it?

When mouse enter:
[image]
When mouse leave:
[image]

And my animation code

```
private void leftOut() {
    KeyFrame k1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(mask.translateXProperty(), 0));
    KeyFrame k2 = new KeyFrame(time, new KeyValue(mask.translateXProperty(), control.getWidth()*-1.0));
    timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(k1,k2);
    timeline.play();
}
```

Other directions are just like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to resize the mask at all. Simply apply a clip to it that has the same size as the image:

```
Image image = new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF.jpg/164px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF.jpg");
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

// init mask
Label mask = new Label("SomeText");
mask.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
mask.setPrefSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
mask.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);");
mask.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

// create clip
Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
mask.setClip(clip);

// keep clip in position horizontally in root
clip.translateXProperty().bind(mask.translateXProperty().negate());

StackPane root = new StackPane(imageView, mask);
root.setPrefSize(500, 500);
root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");

// probably a bit simpler to use TranslateTransition instead of Timeline
TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(5), mask);
transition.setByX(image.getWidth());
transition.play();
```

Comment: Hey, fabian. Thank you very much!!! It works perfectly!!!
I want to use the property “overflow” with CSS at the beginning. But I found that it is not supported in JFx css. And setting a clip for mask can work perfectly, thanks a lot.